# Creating a dictionary without duplicates

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary from a CSV that has no duplicates. The CSV file contains: sample names (s1, s2, etc.) gene names, impact of sample 1 mutation, impact of sample 2 mutation. Here is an example of two lines of the CSV file:

```
s1, s2, gene1, MODERATE, HIGH
s3, s4, gene2, HIGH, MODERATE
```

My goal is to obtain a summary of how many samples have a specific gene mutated, and then whether the mutation is HIGH impact or not.

As an example:

```
gene12  7   ['s1', 's3', 's4', 's10 [HIGH]', 's17', 's19', 's24 [HIGH]']
gene20  2   ['s10 [HIGH]', 's21']
```

Currently my code looks as follows:

```
import os
import sys

path = ("path/to/csv")
open_csv = open(path+"csvfile", "r")
read_csv = open_csv.read().splitlines()
gene_dict = {}
for line in read_csv:
    split_lines = line.split(", ")
    gene = split_lines[2]
    sample1 = split_lines[0]
    sample2 = split_lines[1]
    impact1 = split_lines[3]
    impact2 = split_lines[4]
    for i in range(0, len(read_csv):
        if gene in gene_dict:
            if impact1 == "HIGH":
                gene_dict[gene].append(sample1+" [HIGH]")
            if impact2 == "HIGH":
                gene_dict[gene].append(sample2+" [HIGH]")
            else:
                gene_dict[gene].append(sample1)
                gene_dict[gene].append(sample2)
        else:
            gene_dict[gene] = [sample1]

final_dict = {a:list(set(b)) for a, b in gene_dict.items()}

for key, value in final_dict.items():
    genename = key
    num_samples = len([item for item in value if item])
    samples = value     
    print(genename,num_samples,samples)
```

My script works except that I am getting duplicated samples. What I mean is that if a sample has a HIGH impact mutation in a gene, the final summary will list the sample twice. Below is an example of what I mean:

```
gene12  8   ['s1', 's3', 's4', 's10 [HIGH]', 's17', 's19', 's24', 's24 [HIGH]']
gene20  3   ['s10', 's10 [HIGH]', 's21']
```

It is probably the way that I'm creating the dictionary which is causing the duplication, but I can't figure it out. You'll see that for gene12, s24 is listed twice, throwing off the counts. This also happens for gene20 with s10. The samples are listed twice, once correctly as having a HIGH impact mutation and again as not having a HIGH impact mutation. However, s24 only has a HIGH impact mutation in gene12 and s10 only has a HIGH impact mutation in gene20. I hope this made sense. I can clarify if needed. Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: Could you be more clear about exactly what the format of the csv is?  Are there always two samples/impacts per line?  Can the same gene appear on multiple lines? Can the same sample appear on multiple lines for the same gene with different impacts?

Comment: Yes, there are always two samples and two impacts per line. The same gene can appear on multiple lines. The same sample can appear on different lines but with the same impact for the same gene.

Comment: I would create a class `class gene` and store the object in the dictionary. Give that class an attribute named `status` and add `low` or `high` to it and a `name` attribute. Compare the name attribute before pushing into the dictionary.

Comment: Not sure I completely understand the structure of your script, but the inner loop `for i in range(0, len(read_csv):` looks like it should be removed.

Comment: Well to me it seems like this is happening because in your csv file, you have `s24` with `HIGH` impact and another time without `HIGH` impact which means it'll be appended again without the `HIGH` suffix. To remedy this, you can do a better job of storing the `impact`s or filter `gene_dict` better instead of simply using a `set(b)` call because clearly `'s##' != 's## [HIGH]'`

Comment: I don't know the format of your CSV, but it just seems like it's catching both IF statements. Comment out/replace with `pass` for debug purposes and I bet they'll go away. This way we can confirm what the problem is.

Comment: A longer sample of a csv files and the (incorrect) summary produced from it by your code would be very helpful—and possibly the desired output, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your inner loop `for i in range(0, len(read_csv):` is duplicating and adding useless hits. Also the if/if/else structure and adding the `[HIGH]` mark look broken.

Corrected version:

```
import os
import sys

path = ("path/to/csv")
open_csv = open(path+"csvfile", "r")
read_csv = open_csv.read().splitlines()
gene_dict = {}
for line in read_csv:
    split_lines = line.split(", ")
    gene = split_lines[2]
    sample1 = split_lines[0]
    sample2 = split_lines[1]
    impact1 = split_lines[3]
    impact2 = split_lines[4]
    if impact1 == "HIGH":
        sample1 = sample1 + " [HIGH]"
    if impact2 == "HIGH":
        sample2 = sample2 + " [HIGH]"

    if gene in gene_dict:
        gene_dict[gene].append(sample1)
        gene_dict[gene].append(sample2)
    else:
        gene_dict[gene] = [sample1, sample2]

final_dict = {a:list(set(b)) for a, b in gene_dict.items()}

for key, value in final_dict.items():
    genename = key
    num_samples = len([item for item in value if item])
    samples = value     
    print(genename,num_samples,samples)
```

This looks consistent for the few examples I tried.

Comment: I might be wrong but I think this can still be wrong if a specific `gene` comes up twice once with `HIGH` impact and another without. It will be appended twice into the list as `s##` and `s## [HIGH]` which shouldn't be filtered out by `list(set(b))` call.

Comment: @hqkhan Right, saw the if problem and edited, while you were commenting.

Comment: That should do it as long as the same `sample` doesn't come up for the same gene multiple times. That way we could see something like: `s1, s2, gene1, MODERATE, HIGH`
`s2, s3, gene1, MODERATE, MODERATE` which will add duplicates as OP's problem. But OP hasn't shown that to be the case yet.

Comment: @hqkhan You're right, this is still speculative. And I think still wrong. The `if/else` thing still looks wrong.

Comment: @hqkhan This looks consistent to me for some examples. What do you think?

Comment: Overall I think it looks good. However, I think the problem I mentioned in previous comment is still there (unless you weren't tackling that at all). Using the same example in that comment, we should see `gene_dict['gene1'] = ['s1', 's2 [HIGH]', 's2', 's3']` which will then produce the same issue. But if multiple rows with the same gene aren't an issue (doesn't seem like they are) then this should be fine.

Comment: @hqkhan OP has commented that this cannot happen: "The same sample can appear on different lines but with the same impact for the same gene"

Comment: Ah, whoops missed it. Ty for pointing it out. Yup, then I agree with the solution. Although, I'd much rather see the condition of a duplicate being taken care of upon entry on a smaller list instead of performing a `set()` on a big `list` due to overhead but if that isn't an issue then it's fine.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked great and I can now see that the inner loop was causing me problems. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class like this :

```
class Sample:
    def __init__(self, name, level="low",):
        self.level = level
        self.name = name

    def __eq__(self, equal):
        if equal.name == self.name:
            return True
        return False
```

Something like that (could not test it) :

```
import os
import sys

path = ("path/to/csv")
open_csv = open(path+"csvfile", "r")
read_csv = open_csv.read().splitlines()
gene_dict = {}
for line in read_csv:
    split_lines = line.split(", ")
    gene = split_lines[2]
    sample1 = Sample(split_lines[0])
    sample2 = Sample(split_lines[1])
    impact1 = split_lines[3]
    impact2 = split_lines[4]
    for i in range(0, len(read_csv):
        if gene in gene_dict:
            if not sample1 in gene_dict[gene]:
                if impact1 == "HIGH":
                    sample1.level = impact1
                    gene_dict[gene].append(sample1)

                else:
                    gene_dict[gene].append(sample1)

            if not sample2 in gene_dict[gene]:
                if impact2 == "HIGH":
                    sample2.level = impact2
                    gene_dict[gene].append(sample2)
                else:
                    gene_dict[gene].append(sample2)
        else:
            gene_dict[gene] = [sample1]
```